# Анимация загрузки PyQt

Tags: python, python-3.x, анимация, pyqt, qmovie

Существует некоторое *Python-приложение*, использующее *PyQt5*. 
В процессе его работы иногда происходят события, которые длятся длительное время, например - проверка введённого пароля.

Как реализовать проигрывание, например, **`.gif`** - анимации или чего-то подобного во время такого события?

Минимально-воспроизводимый пример длительного события:

```py
someList = [AbstractUser for AbstractUser in someUserList if (AbstractUser.login == enteredLogin)]

someMatchesList = []

for i in someOtherList:
    try:
        if someList[0].password == (hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', enteredPassword.encode('utf-8'), bytes.fromhex(i), 256256).hex()):
           #Успешный вход
           break
        else:
           someMatchesList.append(False)
           continue

    except IndexError:
        #Неверный логин

if [bool for bool in someMatchesList if (bool == True)] == []:
    #Неверный пароль
```

Comment: Может progressbar?

Comment: а че, у вас пароль медленно проверяется?

Comment: Предоставьте пожалуйста минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует событие, выполняемое длительное время.

Comment: @Victor VosMottor, да

Comment: @S.Nick, я мог бы это сделать, но в таком случае я раскрою механизм работы моей системы шифрования, что я делать не хочу.

Comment: не надо никакой системы шифрования, прочитайте еще раз, что я вам написал.

Comment: хорошо. см.правку.

Comment: вы меня не правильно понимаете. То что вы предоставили, это просто цикл аналогичный `for i in range(random.randint(123456, 12345678)): pass`, по выходу из которого вы анализируете результат. Нужна структура приложения и где в ней вы обрабатываете этот цикл. Вы должны понимать, что тяжелые задачи выполняются в дополнительных потоках, иначе ваш интерфейс блокируется.

Comment: @S.Nick, если я буду демонстрировать структуру приложения, то это невозможно будет сделать в рамках *минимально*-воспроизводимого примера. Проще будет просто дать ссылку на GitHub с кодом. Может быть, лучше сделать так?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112995/discussion-between-starter-and-s-nick).

Comment: Смысл предоставленного мной примера сводится к следующему: если вы запустите предоставленный код, то увидите, что выполнение такого цикла займёт несколько секунд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

События, которые длятся длительное время, необходимо выполнять в дополнительном потоке,
чтобы не блокировать интерфейс.

А проигрывание, например, `.gif`-анимации или чего-то подобного,
это уже зависит от вашего вкуса.

Вот вам простенький вариант, попробуйте.

```
import sys
from random import randint
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal, Qt, QSize, QFile
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, 
    QMessageBox, QSizePolicy, QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie, QPixmap


class Thread(QThread):
    dataThread = pyqtSignal(str)
    
    def __init__(self, username, password, someUserList, someOtherList):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.someUserList = someUserList
        self.someOtherList = someOtherList
        self.someMatchesList = []
        print(username, password, someUserList, someOtherList)

    def run(self):
# !!! vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
#       попробуйте заменить то что ниже своим кодом,
#       события, которого длятся длительное время.
        for i in range(randint(1_000_000, 100_000_000)):
            pass
        if i > 50_000_000:
            self.dataThread.emit(f"successfully")
        else:
            self.dataThread.emit(f"error")
# !!! ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


class LoginPage(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.image_label = QLabel(alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.image_label.setPixmap(QPixmap("head3.png"))
        self.login_label = QLabel(text=self.tr("LOG IN"), alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        font = self.login_label.font()
        font.setPointSize(30)
        self.login_label.setFont(font)
        self.login_label.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        
        self.email_username_lineedit = QLineEdit(placeholderText=self.tr("Email or username"))
        self.password_lineedit = QLineEdit(placeholderText=self.tr("Password"), 
                                           echoMode=QLineEdit.Password)
            
        self.enter_button = QPushButton(self.tr("Enter"))
        self.enter_button.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)
        
        self.forgot_password_label = QLabel(self.tr("Forgot password?"), alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.forgot_password_label.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Fixed)

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.setSpacing(0)
        lay.addWidget(self.image_label)
        lay.addWidget(self.login_label)
        lay.addWidget(self.email_username_lineedit)
        lay.addWidget(self.password_lineedit)
        lay.addWidget(self.enter_button)
        lay.addWidget(self.forgot_password_label)
        
        # я не знаю, что вам надо будет передавать в дополнительный поток
        self.someUserList = []                                       # Какой-то список
        self.someOtherList = []                                      # Какой-то список
        
        self.loader_file = QMovie("img/Fo2BxBK.gif")
        self.loader_file.start()
        self.loader_label = QLabel(self) 
        self.loader_label.setMovie(self.loader_file)
        self.loader_label.adjustSize()
        self.loader_label.hide()
        
    def button_clicked(self):
        self.enter_button.setDisabled(True)
        if not self.email_username_lineedit.text() or not self.password_lineedit.text():
            msg = QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Внимание', 'Заполните все поля!') 
            self.enter_button.setDisabled(False)
            return
        self.loader_label.show()
        overlayLabel = QLabel('<h1 style="color: red">Please wait..<h1>', self.loader_label)
        overlayLabel.move(100, self.loader_label.height()-30)
        overlayLabel.show()

        # я не знаю, что вам надо будет передавать в дополнительный поток.
        # Предположим что передать надо: логин, пароль и какие-то два списка
        self.worker = Thread(self.email_username_lineedit.text(),
                             self.password_lineedit.text(),
                             self.someUserList,
                             self.someOtherList
                            )
        self.worker.dataThread.connect(self.data_validation)
        self.worker.start()   

    def data_validation(self, text):
        self.loader_label.hide()        
        self.enter_button.setDisabled(False)
        if text == 'error':
            msg = QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Внимание', 
                    'Что-то пошло не так!<br>Проверьте правильность написания вводимой информации.')
        else:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', '<h1>successfully</h1>')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = LoginPage()
    w.resize(320, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]